# Fields of custom view are null after inflating - databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, nullpointerexception

I have a problem with my code that drives me crazy.

I use `DataBinding` in my `Fragment`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_appointment, container, false);
    mViewModel = new AppointmentViewModel(((DetailActivity) getActivity()).getSalonId());
    mBinding.setViewModel(mViewModel);
    mBinding.datePopup.setViewModel(mViewModel);
```

And want to use `DataBinding`too in my `CustomView`

```
public class DatePopupView extends FrameLayout {
private Date mPickedDate = null;
private CustomDatePopupViewBinding mBinding = null;

public DatePopupView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setup();
}

public DatePopupView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setup();
}

public void setup() {
    mPickedDate = new Date();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    mBinding = CustomDatePopupViewBinding.inflate(inflater, this, true);}
```

And after the inflating is done in `onCreateView` this is called in the same `CustomView` class:

```
public void setViewModel(AppointmentViewModel viewModel) {
    mBinding.setViewModel(viewModel);
}
```

The problem is that i get a `NullPointerException` in this method.

In my opinion this is not possible because the `CustomView`object is already instantiated and the fields are set.

If it were not, i could not access the `CustomView` through `mBinding.datePopup`.

Please help me understanding this;P

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that should be fixed in Android Studio 2.2 release. If it is the same bug, the data binding framework isn't properly ignoring the already bound view that you're inflating as part of your constructor when binding the outer view (FragmentAppointmentBinding).

Comment: Thanks.
I am using 2.2 Preview7

Comment: I was using 2.2 Preview 7, and now using 2.2 Beta-1. Still not working :(

Comment: It may not be the same bug. Can you post a link to a project that reproduces the issue or submit a bug on Android.com with one?

Comment: 2022 still bug...